# How to sort data within groups and count the elements of each group in R?

Tags: r, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort a dataframe by column(s) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns-in-r)

everyone:
    I want to sort the data within groups using R. For example:
the data is:

```
geneID  Nr.annotation
CL1002  uncharacterized
CL1002  uncharacterized
CL1002  uncharacterized
CL1002  uncharacterized
CL1002  uncharacterized
CL1002  uncharacterized
CL1019  PREDICTED:
CL1019  PREDICTED:
CL1019  predicted
CL1019  PREDICTED:
CL1019  PREDICTED:
CL1019  predicted
CL1019  predicted
CL1019  hypothetical
CL10246 unnamed
CL10246 predicted
CL10246 unnamed
CL10246 unnamed
CL10246 unnamed
CL10246 unnamed
CL10246 unnamed
CL1064  octicosapeptide/Phox/Bem1p
CL1064  octicosapeptide/Phox/Bem1p
CL1064  serine/threonine
CL1064  serine/threonine
CL1064  serine/threonine
CL1064  serine/threonine
```

This is the original data. Please copy and use the code as follows:

```
read.table("clipboard",strip.white=T,header=T)
```

And then, what should I do? After sorted, I want the result to be this:

```
geneID  Nr.annotation
CL1002  PREDICTED:
CL1002  uncharacterized    4
CL1019  PREDICTED:         6
CL1019  hypothetical       1
CL1019  uncharacterized    1
CL10246 predicted          1
CL10246 unnamed            6
CL1064  octicosapeptide/Phox/Bem1p  2
CL1064  serine/threonine   4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `plyr` and `arrange`. All you are doing is ordering first by one column, then the next

```
library(plyr)

arrange(DF,geneID, Nr.annotation)
```

(on second looking, your example output does not quite make sense. How are you getting a combination of

`CL1002  PREDICTED:`

Comment: arrange(DF,DF$geneID,DF$Nr,annotation)->z
Error in order(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  : 
  argument lengths differ

Comment: Why have you included the `$` references? There is no need when using `arrange`  (and my solution doesn't suggest it)

Comment: you are right. I made a mistake and you solution works. Thanks a lot.